# HttpServer and Julia error with match method

Tags: http, julia

I'm trying to understand how to work with this package for Julia.

Im using the following code (is an example from the package):

```
using HttpServer

function fibonacci(n)
  if n == 1 return 1 end
  if n == 2 return 1 end
  prev = BigInt(1)
  pprev = BigInt(1)
  for i=3:n
    curr = prev + pprev 
    pprev = prev
    prev = curr
  end
  return prev
end

http = HttpHandler() do req::Request, res::Response
    m = match(r"^/fibo/(\d+)/?$",req.resource)
    if m == nothing 
        return Response(404) 
    end
    number = BigInt(m.captures[1])
    if number < 1 || number > 100_000 
        return Response(500) 
    end
    return Response(string(fibonacci(number)))
end

http.events["error"]  = (client, err) -> println(err)
http.events["listen"] = (port)        -> println("Listening on $port...")

server = Server(http)
run(server, 8031)
```

And trying to access to the server with this link:

> http://localhost:8031/fibo/100

But i get the next error:

> MethodError(convert,(BigInt,"100"))
>
> ERROR: MethodError: Cannot`convert` an object of type
>   SubString{String} to an object of type BigInt

What im doing wrong?

I have problems to figure out what `r"^/fibo/(\d+)/?` does, maybe there is my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because method `BigInt(s::AbstractString)` is deprecated and was remove in julia 0.5. Use `number = parse(BigInt,m.captures[1])` instead.